# Windows Notepad, how can I disable saved find-and-replace values?

Tags: windows-registry, find-and-replace, notepad

In Windows' Notepad, when I use the find-and-replace feature, it saves the values I used therein and displays them next time I use the feature. I don't want it do. How can I disable this?

I can see that the values are being stored in the registry here:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\searchString, a REG_SZ
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\replaceString, a REG_SZ

I have tried these things, with no lasting success:
->Delete the searchString and replaceString values (notepad just recreates them)
->Create searchString and replaceString binary values (notepad just recreates them as string values)
->Delete the Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad registry key (notepad just recreates them, and this wipes out other data, like window position, that I want to keep)

Comment: Where I have looked, the ability to retain Find/Replace history has been very recently added with no ability I can see to turn it off. You may need another editor like Notepad++.  I use either Notepad or UltraEdit

Comment: That is consistent with my impression, too: It only started happening very recently, maybe the past one or two weeks.